# How to insert a record from an iOS swift app to an Azure mobile service database?

Tags: ios, xcode, azure, swift

Without getting too complicated, how to upload a single quantum of data from an iOS app (using Swift) to an Azure mobile service database?

Specifically, how to *actually* use the table insert method which requires a MSItemBlock closure?

Here's the decorated method I'm hunting down:

```
itemTable.insert(<#item: NSDictionary?#>, completion: <#MSItemBlock?#>)
```

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes you just want to do *one simple thing* without building an entirely perfect solution.

In my case, *all* I wanted was to insert/upload a record from my iOS app (using core data) to my Azure mobile service database. I didn’t want to use table controllers or full table management objects (not yet anyway) - just a brief “proof-of-concept” to test out a basic save and upload pattern.

**What I had in place:**

- iOS app built in Xcode 6 using swift
- CoreData linked up and working nicely

**What I wanted to do:**

- *After* saving to local core data in my app, *also* insert a corresponding record to my Azure mobile service database

**What I did:**

- Logged into my Azure portal and navigated to my mobile service
- Selected the iOS platform, then opened the “*Connect an existing iOS
  app*” link.

  Followed the on screen instructions to:
- Download the iOS SDK
- Create an "Item" table (by simply clicking the provided button)

**What I did next:**

- Dragged the downloaded sdk into my Xcode project
- In my *Bridging-Header.h* file (generated for me by Xcode when I had
  previously run “*Create NSManagedObject Subclass…*” commands on my
  core data models) I added this import:

  ```
  #import "WindowsAzureMobileServices/WindowsAzureMobileServices.h"
  ```
- In *AppDelegate.swift* I added a constant reference to the AzureClient:

  ```
  let client = MSClient(applicationURLString: "https://mymobileapp.azure-mobile.net/", applicationKey: “aAaBbBcCc…")
  ```

**Finally:**

- Here's the function I was wanting to use:

  ```
  itemTable.insert(<#item: NSDictionary?#>, completion: <#MSItemBlock?#>)
  ```
- Accordingly, and in swift parlance, I used the following to insert a record up to
  Azure heaven:

  ```
  var client = AppDelegate().client // To reference my constant in AppDelegate.swift

  var itemTable:MSTable = client.tableWithName("Item")
  var itemToInsert:NSDictionary = ["text":"My Awesome Item 1"]

  itemTable.insert(itemToInsert,
      completion: {
          insertedItem, error in
          if error{
              println("error: \(error)")
          }
          else{
              println("Success!")
          }
      }
  )
  ```

The expected/returned ***MSItemBlock*** in the insert method stumped me for a while until I read up a little on swift *closures* vs objc *blocks*.

*Disclaimer*: The above snippet worked for me in this particular case but in truth I'm a drunken monkey playing with matches at the moment, so I do realise there must be far more efficient ways of doing this. However, I could find absolutely nothing on the web about the MSItemBlock and its pattern of usage in ***Swift***, so hopefully this might prove a *starting* point for anybody else struggling with a similar issue.

Comment: how do you extract the id of the insertedItem in the completion block?

Answer (score 1):

The iOS Swift quickstart for Azure Mobile Services will be available for download next portal update.  In the meantime you can see it here, here's the insert line:

https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/blob/dev/quickstart/iOS-Swift/ZUMOAPPNAME/ZUMOAPPNAME/ToDoTableViewController.swift#L148

Inserting an item to the table should look like:

```
let originalItem = ["key":"value"];
itemTable.insert(originalItem) {
   (item, error) in
   // Logic here
}
```